# Lost my workshop on island 4, can I make a new one?

Tags: black-and-white

Is it possible to make a workshop from scratch? I am stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been ages since I played this game, which holds a special place in my heart, so sadly I can only offer this bit of text from the B&W wiki:

> A workshop is a civic building that can be used by the player to create scaffoldings. To make one, a player must combine three scaffoldings and place them at a village that either has all civic buildings or just a village store.

Comment: I think that is the best answer that exists on the internet. Luckily I had a save state from third island near the end. I am not sure if the game made one for more automatically. I replayed island 4 with more resources and people from island 3 via the vortex. I also used the time slowdown feature on island 4 to deflect the fireballs. Now I am in good shape! I just hope I don't run into any glitches on island 5.